Fixing Previous Owner Modified Sliding Windows
I'm trying to fix several (6) windows in my house where the locks don't line up and the windows don't slide smoothly. I took one panel off to see what was going on and it looks like there has been some DIY modifications to the window.
The previous owner screwed on this wooden panel into the base of the track:

Then they used sheetrock screws to screw on this metal track:

My question is how do I fix this? I'm not even sure what this is supposed to look like. It seems like the metal tracks fit this window but the sheetrock screws were just shot through it and don't seem correct. I tried searching but I don't know what terminology I'm looking for or how this all fits together.

Presumably the original window hardware (probably rollers) failed and for whatever reason some prior person chose not to replace with the same - possibly because the hardware was not available, or was so poorly designed that repeated failure could be expected, or both due to putting the manufacturer out of business.
Remove the tracks and see what you have for places to mount hardware, or identify the window and look up what it should have, and what, if any, replacement parts are available.
Then either follow the path of buying parts to make it like it was, or re-engineer a different solution from parts actually available. Or go the third and very expensive route of replacing the windows to get a new self-compatible set of hardware.
On the re-engineering front, in-line skate wheels and/or skateboard bearings are pretty good rollers that fit in most window tracks/frames and may be more favorably priced than specialized rollers for a particular obsolete window, if you can mount them in a way that they can work. Then again, patio door rollers are not too expensive and a commonly used approach for sliding windows of any size.

This track was installed to compensate for the loss of the original track and roller assembly.
You will have to remove the track from the sash to determine the actual mounting arrangement for the wheels.
I agree with Ecnerwal's option to budget for the replacement of all of the windows. Searching for parts to fit properly so that the windows will latch is not a durable solution.
